# react-native-modal-datetime-picker showing only current date

Tags: react-native, react-native-picker, react-native-datetimepicker

I'm using `react-native-modal-datetime-picker` in my React Native app on iOS, and when the modal pops up, instead of having a range of dates to scroll through, it shows only the current date:

[image]

```
<DateTimePickerModal
    datePickerModeAndroid={'spinner'}
    mode={'date'}
    is24Hour={false}
    isVisible={this.state.isDatePickerVisible}
    onConfirm={() => {}}
    onCancel={() => {}}/>
```

`react-native-modal-datetime-picker@8.9.3`
`react-native@0.63.4`

Does anyone know how to approach solving this?

Comment: Does this happen on the real device only or also on your simulator?

Comment: @DavidScholz Both, emulator and real device

Comment: I've tried it using `react-native-modal-datetime-picker@13.0.1` and it works on my setup. Are you allowed to upgrade? It might work in the newer version.

Comment: I'm not able to upgrade the react-native version, and it seems like I can't upgrade react-native-modal-datetime-picker beyond 8.9.3 with react-native@0.63.4. I can mess around with that more though. What version of react-native are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Just add `display={"spinner"}`

Your device/simulator use default display style which is calendar and in calendar case above UI will be render.

Example Code:

```
<DateTimePickerModal
    date={this.props.currentDate || undefined}
    maximumDate={this.props.maximumDate}
    minimumDate={this.props.minimumDate}
    mode="date"
    onCancel={this.onCancel}
    onConfirm={this.onConfirm}
    isVisible={this.state.modalOpened}
    display={this.props.display}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. add  display = 'spinner'

   and inside ios->myappname->AppDelegate.m add these lines inside
   didfinishlaunch options;

```
    
    if (@available(iOS 14, *)) {
        UIDatePicker *picker = [UIDatePicker appearance];
        picker.preferredDatePickerStyle = UIDatePickerStyleWheels;  }
```